# Отключить всплывающее окно

Tags: ассемблер, дизассемблирование, обратная-разработка

Дан exe'шник программы, в которой, по истечении некоторого времени, всплывает назойливое окно. Доступа к исходному коду нет, программа была пропущена через дизассемблер. Мне удалось отключить таймер на кнопке окей, чтобы не ждать 10 секунд прежде чем выключить всплывающее окно. Но как полностью убрать нагскрин, я не могу понять.

```
.00401590: 56                             push        esi   
.00401591: 8BF1                           mov         esi,ecx 
.00401593: E806030000                     call        MFC42.4710 --↓1
.00401598: 8B4620                         mov         eax,[esi][020]
.0040159B: 6A00                           push        0
.0040159D: 6A64                           push        064 ;'d' 
.0040159F: 6A03                           push        3
.004015A1: 50                             push        eax
.004015A2: FF15E4214000                   call        SetTimer 
.004015A8: 6A00                           push        0
.004015AA: 8D4E64                         lea         ecx,[esi][064]
.004015AD: C7466000000000                 mov         d,[esi][060],0
.004015B4: E8FD020000                     call        MFC42.2642 --↓2
.004015B9: B801000000                     mov         eax,1
.004015BE: 5E                             pop         esi
.004015BF: C3                             retn ; -^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-
.004015C0: 83EC0C                         sub         esp,00C 
.004015C3: 56                             push        esi 
.004015C4: 8BF1                           mov         esi,ecx  
.004015C6: 8B5660                         mov         edx,[esi][060]
.004015C9: 42                             inc         edx
.004015CA: 8BC2                           mov         eax,edx 
.004015CC: 895660                         mov         [esi][060],edx
.004015CF: 83F800                         cmp         eax,0
.004015D2: 7E34                           jle        .000401608 --↓3
.004015D4: 8B4620                         mov         eax,[esi][020]
.004015D7: 57                             push        edi 
.004015D8: 6A03                           push        3
.004015DA: 50                             push        eax
.004015DB: FF15E8214000                   call        KillTimer  
.004015E1: 8D7E64                         lea         edi,[esi][064]
.004015E4: 6A01                           push        1 
.004015E6: 8BCF                           mov         ecx,edi
.004015E8: E8C9020000                     call        MFC42.2642 --↓1
.004015ED: 6824304000                     push        000403024 --↓2 
.004015F2: 8BCF                           mov         ecx,edi
.004015F4: E8C3020000                     call        MFC42.6199 --↓3
.004015F9: 5F                             pop         edi
.004015FA: 8BCE                           mov         ecx,esi
.004015FC: E8A3020000                     call        MFC42.2379 --↓4
.00401601: 5E                             pop         esi
.00401602: 83C40C                         add         esp,00C
.00401605: C20400                         retn        4 ; -^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-^-
.00401608: B964000000                     mov         ecx,000000064 ;'   d'
```

Comment: Отключить второй таймер, срабатывание которого вызывает открытие окна.

Comment: На что ориентироваться в поиске функции, которая отвечает за активацию этого таймера? Если поставить nop в settimer, программа перестает корректно работать.

Comment: Нужно нопами забить и вызов функции, и все пуши перед ним.